# How to update array of embedded collection field based on another collection embedded field value in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, embedded-documents

I've searched in this forum for my below issue and I'm not able to find solution.

### Inventory collction:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("555b1978af015394d1016374"),
"Billno" : "ABC1",
"Device_id" : "strsdedgfrtg12",
"item" : [ 
    {
        "item_id" : 232,
        "size" : "S",
        "qty" : 25
    }, 
    {
        "item_id" : 272,
        "size" : "M",
        "qty" : 5
    }
],
"category" : "clothing"
```

}

inventory_new collection:

---

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("555b1978af015394d1016374"),
"Billno" : "ABC1",
"Device_id" : "strsdedgfrtg12",
"item" : [ 
    {
        "item_id" : 232,
        "size" : "S",
        "qty" : 25
    }, 
    {
        "item_id" : 272,
        "size" : "M",
        "qty" : 5000
    }
],
"category" : "clothing"
```

}

Now I've to update the inventory collection embedded array's item "qty" with inventory_new collections embedded item "qty" field value.. I've tried below code.. But I'm not succeed. Please advice.

```
db.inventory.find().forEach(function (doc1) {
var doc2 = db.inventory_copy.find({ Billno: doc1.Billno},{ Device_id: doc1.Device_id},{ item.item_id: doc1.item.item_id}, {item.qty: 1 });
if (doc2 != null) {
    doc1.item.qty = doc2.item.qty;
    db.inventory.save(doc1);
}
```

});

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following update:

```
db.inventory.find().forEach(function (doc1) {
    var doc2 = db.inventory_copy.findOne(
        { 
            "Billno": doc1.Billno, 
            "Device_id": doc1.Device_id,
            "item.item_id": doc1.item.item_id
        }
    );
    if (doc2 != null) { 
        doc1.item = doc2.item;    
        db.inventory.save(doc1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi  I've to check embedded document's filed in find() like                          var doc2 = db.inventory_copy.find({ Billno: doc1.Billno},{ Device_id: doc1.Device_id},{ item.item_id: doc1.item.item_id}, {item.qty: 1 });
if (doc2 != null) {

Comment: @Root I've added extra details.

Comment: Hi  I'm getting error :          uncaught exception: error: {
 "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue cannot compare to undefined",
 "code" : 17287
}

Comment: Hi,  Anyone have idea?